# How to prevent RAM from filling up in image Classification (DL)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am new in ML and have a problem.
I have 10000 images (300,300)px. I want to give them into the DL model for classification. but my problem is when I Normalize the images (convert each image from uint8 to float and divide to 255), my Ram crashed! I mean, my Google Colab RAM fills up.

- Is there a solution or technique for this problem ?
- Is there a way that (for example) I can divide my data into 3 parts (3300 images in each part) then normalize and giving this part to the model for training separately? (and after part1, empty the RAM and part2 Normalize+trainin)

Thanks.

this is my code:

```
data_train = np.asarray(data_train)
data_train = data_train.astype('float16') #data_train.shape: (10000, 300, 300, 3)
data_valid = np.asarray(data_valid)
data_valid = data_valid.astype('float16')

data_train/=255.0  #This part fills my memory !! 
data_valid/=255.0  #This part fills my memory !!

model = #confing the model ...
model.compile(loss=... ,optimizer=...,metrics=...)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(...)
datagen.fit(data_train)
history = model.fit(datagen.flow(data_train,labels_train,batch_size=...),
                    steps_per_epoch=...,
                    epochs=...,
                    validation_data=(data_valid,labels_valid))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we don't load all the data once (10,000 images in your case). The minimum number of images you need to load to the memory at once is your batch size. 
For your second question - yes, it is the accepted way to deal with large datasets. First, you have to load only `batch_size` number of images normalize and feed to the classifier. See if [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/) helps for your implementation.